# Write to same file from multiple tasks (Gulp, Node, gulp-json)

Tags: node.js, gulp

I've just started using Gulp (and NodeJs)... Obviously I ran into my first wall.

Here it is:
I have a large project that uses themes. Each theme has it's own assets (scss and js files). Here is my gulpfile.js:

```
// < require block here (not included, to keep this short)

var themes = ["theme1", "theme2", "theme3"];

// Since I can have up to 20 different themes, I use the 'themes' array so I can create tasks dynamically, like this:
themes.forEach(function (theme) {
    gulp.task('css:' + theme, function () {
        setVersion([theme], 'css'); // write asset version into a json file
        gulp.src('../themes/frontend/' + theme + '/assets/css/style.scss')
            .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
            .pipe(sass({outputStyle: 'compressed'}).on('error', sass.logError))
            .pipe(sourcemaps.write('./'))
            .pipe(gulp.dest('../themes/frontend/' + theme + '/assets/css'))
    });
});

// Of course, I need an "all" task to build all CSS in rare ocasions I need to do so:
gulp.task('css:all', ("css:" + themes.join(",css:")).split(","));
// ("css:" + themes.join(",css:")).split(",") => results in the needed ['css:theme1', 'css:theme2'] tasks array

// The same logic as above for JS files
// but added the use of gulp-concat and gulp-uglify
// Having scripts = { "theme1" : ['script1', 'script2'], "theme2": ['script1', 'script2'] }
// ...

// And "per theme" both "css and js"
themes.forEach(function (theme) {
    gulp.task('theme:' + theme, ['css:' + theme, 'js:' + theme]);
});


// Next I need to set versions for each asset
// I'm writing all the versions into a json file

assetsVersion = someRandomGeneratedNumber;
function setVersion(themes, assetType) {
/**
 * themes: array
 * assetType: 'all', 'css' or 'js'
 */
    var fs = require('fs'),
        path = require("path");
    var versionsFilePath = path.normalize(__dirname + '/../protected/config/theme/frontend/');
    var versionsFileName = '_assets-version.json';

    if (!fs.existsSync(versionsFilePath + versionsFileName)) {
        // Create file if it doesn't exist
        fs.writeFile(versionsFilePath + versionsFileName, "{}", function (err) {
            if (err) {
                return console.log(err);
            }
        });
    }

    gulp.src(versionsFilePath + versionsFileName)
        .pipe(jeditor(function (json) {
            themes.forEach(function(theme) {
                if ("undefined" == typeof (json[theme])) {
                    json[theme] = {};
                }

                if ('css' == assetType) {
                    json[theme]['css'] = assetsVersion;
                } else if ('js' == assetType) {
                    json[theme]['js'] = assetsVersion;
                } else {
                    json[theme] = {"css": assetsVersion, "js": assetsVersion};
                }
                if ("undefined" == typeof(json[theme]['css'])) {
                    // if we're missing the 'css' key (i.e. we've just created the json file), add that too
                    json[theme]['css'] = assetsVersion;
                }
                if ("undefined" == typeof(json[theme]['js'])) {
                    // if we're missing the 'js' key (i.e. we've just created the json file), add that too
                    json[theme]['js'] = assetsVersion;
                }
            });
            return json;
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(versionsFilePath));
}
```

The assets versioning json should look like this:

```
{
  "theme1": {
    "css": "20150928163236",
    "js": "20150928163236"
  },
  "theme2": {
    "css": "20150928163236",
    "js": "20150928163236"
  },
  "theme3": {
    "css": "20150928163236",
    "js": "20150928163236"
  }
}
```

running 'gulp css:theme#' - works fine...
BUT running 'gulp css:all' - makes a messy json
Of course, this happens because all css:theme# (or js:theme#) tasks run async, and more often than not there are multiple tasks writing simultaneously to my json file.

I've read about tasks depending on other tasks, but that doesn't really fit into my whole "dynamic tasks" flow (or I don't know how to fit it in).
I mean I don't think that this:

```
gulp.task('css:theme1', ['versioning'], function() {
  //do stuff after 'versioning' task is done.
});
```

would help me. SO what if it waits for the version to be written? Multiple tasks would still write to the file at the same time. Also, for this to work, I would need to pass parameters that I also don't know how to do... like:

```
gulp.task('css:'+theme, ['versioning --theme ' + theme], function() {
      //do stuff after 'versioning' task is done.
    });
```

Like I could make it work in the console. I know this isn't working, BUT would be really useful in some cases if it would somehow be possible to send parameters to the task in the task name.

Neither runSequence() { ... done(); }, I really don't see how could I make it work within my flow...

Please, anybody... help a newb...
How can I solve this, while:

1. Having tasks created dynamically;
2. Having one versioning json file for all themes.

Comment: have you tried merge2 or merge-stream?

Comment: hmm... I've just looked up 'merge-stream'... But I'm not sure how to implement in my scenario.

Comment: i haven't tried it myself, but something like mergeStream(streamsArray).pipe(gulp.dest(blah));

Comment: I don't think it helps... or I just don't see it... I mean I'm thinking of something like this? : 
stream.add(['what needs to be added']; in every task... and...? what then?
Have a stream with all the versions and then put that into my json file? The question still remains: "WHEN" to write to the json file?
How do I know when any task is done? I somehow need to know that "all ran tasks are finished, which ever those might be".

Comment: Also, if I simply try: var stream = merge2(['some array']); stream.add(['another array']); like in their example, I get "Only readable streams cand be merged" and they say it shouldn't as of v0.3.4

Comment: can you provide a minimal example to your test case which can be run easily?

Comment: "minimal example which can be run easily"... like my "package.json" and "gulpfile.js" files?
I'll be able to do that tomorrow, 'till then I'm just using a unique assets version for all themes... Modifying one theme's assets leads to recaching css and js files for all themes. Not good, but working until tomorrow. Couldn't figure things out yet, or maybe I'm too tired...

Comment: probably that would need some files as well, so that gulp actually builds something.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90871/discussion-between-mrcroft-and-ilj).